# Repeat the same operations in multiple files in R

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

I want to repeat the same operations in multiple files that have the same format [1:1259]. Each file has a column name *Image* in which I want to extract a number and create another column with it.

The code I want to repeat to each of my files.

```
r<- regexpr("\\d+", Seg_grow_1mm.csv[,"Image"])
Seg_grow_1mm_01<- Seg_grow_1mm.csv %>%
  mutate(., new_id=(regmatches(Seg_grow_1mm.csv[,"Image"], r)))
```

Preview of Seg_grow_1mm_01

```
#   ID    Image                                                                    New_id
#   02     /Users/LLG/Data avec smoothing-margin/CHUM/05/Augmentation 3 mm/           05
#   03     /Users/LLG/Data avec smoothing-margin/CHUM/103/Augmentation 3 mm/          103
#   04     /Users/LLG/Data avec smoothing-margin/CHUM/145/Augmentation 3 mm/          145
# ....
```

I want to repeat this operation to each of my files.  I tried with a loop without success and I don’t know how to transform it into a function so I can use lapply on my list of files.

```
seg = list.files(path=csv, pattern="*.csv") # Seg[1:3]

for (i in 1:length(seg))
  assign(seg[i], read.csv(seg[i]))for (x in seg)
      r<- regexpr("\\d+", x[,"Image"])
      mutate(., new_id=(regmatches( x[,"Image"], r)))

Error in x[, "Image"] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

I don't know what to put at the ??.

```
seg01<- lapply(seg, function (z)
  {r<- regexpr("\\d+", ?? [,"Image"])
  mutate(., new_id=(regmatches( ?? [,"Image"], r)))})
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227 is a good discussion about working with lists-of-frames/tables.

Comment: @r2evans, thank you for the link, but it's not helping me with my problem...

Comment: Okay, sorry about that. Not sure what else I can suggest without an idea of what the data looks like though. You don't have to show all 1000+ columns to demonstrate what you need out of one. I'm not sure if this is a question about how to use `lapply`, how to deal with multiple files, or how to extract a number from a string (regex or otherwise).

Comment: Sorry if it’s not clear … English is not my first language and I’m still new with R.  I created a small preview of my file (dput(head(de) was horrible …) My question is really about how to do the regular expression to every file of my list seg. I can do it for every file individually. For now ,I have 3 files so it’s easy to just copy in past the code 3 times, even though it’s not efficient, but soon I will have 15 csv files in my list seg.

Comment: So, you have a list of files named similar to `Seg_grow_1mm_01`. Those files share the same structure (as a data.frame) like shown in your preview. And now you want to extract the numbers in the `image` column (the `05`, `103`, `145` in your example) and put them into a new column for every data.frame?

Comment: I'm so not clear sorry ... I have a list of files like Seg_grow_1mm.csv and I want to create a list of files like Seg_grow_1mm_01. The Seg_grow_1mm_01 file has the new column "new_id".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `tidyverse` approach:

```r
seg <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")

library(purrr)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

seg %>% 
  map(read_csv) %>% 
  map(~ .x %>% 
        mutate(new_id = str_extract(Image, "(?<=/)\\d+(?=/)"))) %>% 
  `names<-`(.,seg)
```

creates a named list of data.frames/tibbles

```r
$example1.csv
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  ID    Image                                                             new_id
  <chr> <chr>                                                             <chr> 
1 02    /Users/LLG/Data avec smoothing-margin/CHUM/05/Augmentation 3 mm/  05    
2 03    /Users/LLG/Data avec smoothing-margin/CHUM/103/Augmentation 3 mm/ 103   
3 04    /Users/LLG/Data avec smoothing-margin/CHUM/145/Augmentation 3 mm/ 145   

$example2.csv
# A tibble: 3 x 3
     ID Image                                           new_id   
  <dbl> <chr>                                           <chr>    
1    23 /example/directory/1983/Augmentation 3 mm/      1983     
2    42 /example/directory/105123/Augmentation 3 mm/    105123   
3    99 /example/directory/151252145/Augmentation 3 mm/ 151252145
```

based on my two example files. Using `assign` you could create data.frames in your Global Enviroment, but that shouldn't be necessary.

If you want to write this list back into seperate `.csv`-files, you could use

```r
seg %>% 
  map(read_csv) %>% 
  map(~ .x %>% 
        mutate(new_id = str_extract(Image, "(?<=/)\\d+(?=/)"))) %>% 
  `names<-`(.,seg) %>%
  map2(.x = .,
       .y = paste("new_", seg),
       ~ write_csv(x = .x, file = .y))
```

This creates files with a prefix `new_` and the old filename in your current working directory. If you want your filenames like "oldfilename_01.csv", just replace the `paste("new_", seg)` with `str_replace(seg, "\\.csv", "_01\\.csv")`.

Comment: Hi @Martin Gal, thanks for the answer. I don't understand how I can read each individual file ? And how do I write a csv for each element of the list?

Comment: Your code uses the `list.files()` function. This function creates a vector of filenames. We use this list, to read the `.csv`-files into a list of data.frames (that's the `map(read_csv)`-part). Perhaps you have to set the working directory to the directory containing the `.csv`-files first. You can do so with `setwd("PATHtoYOURfiles")`.

Comment: @TchatCusson I edited my answer to clearify it. Hope this helpes.

Comment: where can I find more useful information on map() ?

Comment: This is a good start: https://www.rebeccabarter.com/blog/2019-08-19_purrr/